# git - remove file from the repository

Tags: git

I know there's a million similar questions already, but I'm not sure they apply. I am new to `git`, and have a project hosted on github. I accidentally added some big log files to the repository. When I noticed it, I `git rm`-ed them and then `commit`-ted the changes. That seems to have done the job, in that when I clone the repository, I get only the files I wanted (source code). However, the cloning now takes forever, because, I assume, git is still downloading those log files for some reason (the .git repository is now huge, although the main project files weigh a meg or so). How can I get rid of that bloat now?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try and follow the **[GitHub guide "remove sensitive data"](http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/)**

> From time to time users accidentally commit data like passwords or keys into a git repo. While you can use `git rm` to remove the file, it will still be in the repo’s history. Fortunately, git makes it fairly simple to remove the file from the entire repo history.