# How can I remove a file from a Git repository, including history, and following renames?

Tags: git

This question is extremely similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730411/git-remove-file-from-the-repository) but with the caveat that I need to remove all previous versions of the file including renamed versions.  Basically I'm looking for the solution [found here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) but including the fact that maybe 6 months ago I renamed "Rakefile_test" to "Rakefile" and "Rakefile_test" must be removed from the Git history as well.

To clarify: I do not know which files have been renamed or what their old names were.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove both files (assuming that there wasn't a *different* file with the same name before the rename):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile Rakefile_test' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I don't know which files have been renamed.  I only know the name of the file as it is at the head of the branch.

Comment: @Rotsiser Give up. Git doesn't track renames, it *detects* them. The necessary information for this task isn't even in the repository.

Comment: Ha, I'm not in the habit of giving up.  I assume this task is possible since `git log --follow` can come up with the required information (I think).