# Delete a file from Git

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git - remove file from the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730411/git-remove-file-from-the-repository)

I have mistakenly pushed a big file around(900MB) into git repo. Now i want to remove that file from that particular commit . Otherwise it will take too much of time for pull. Help me please...

Comment: This may helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047465/how-to-delete-a-file-from-git-repo

Comment: I want to remove that file from entire git log....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2730411/291641 about removing sensitive data which is an equivalent task to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good blog which explains how to identify very large files checked into the git repository and rewrite the history to delete them.

http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history/

its worked!